# Is there a native iOS element that looks and behaves like iOS passcode on main screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to achieve the same effect as the one on the main screen of an iOS device, where a user has to type in his password in order to proceed. I know about setting the keyboard input to numbers, but I was wondering if the neat one that is used when unlocking your iPhone is custom made by Apple, or somehow accessible.

Comment: I would like to add, that I have seen other apps using it and I was wondering if they did it themselves, or somehow recycled the "native" way Apple does it with iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inbuilt/customizable view from Apple to show passcode screen in your App.

There is no direct XCode element is available. But you can construct the view which will act as passcode screen by having UILabel,UIView & UIButton XCode elements.

[This is an example of that](https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHPasscodeViewController)

[Even More samples you could find here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=passcode%20ios%20github)

Comment: I'm trying to find out if there is any native component for entering the passcode in iOS and I came across your comment. Wanted to know whether there isn't still such component or is there one?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native component that does all of this out of the box. You could implement this component from scratch by adding four labels and an invisible textfield in a super view. Then you can customise the appearance of the labels to resemble the native passcode input. Additionally, you can use this to animate the shaking effect:

```
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation( keyPath:"transform" )
animation.values = [NSValue( CATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-x, 0, 0 ) ), NSValue( CATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation( x, 0, 0 ) )]
animation.repeatCount = 2
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.duration = 0.05
view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "shake")
```

You can choose the value of x to make the animation shake more or less.

Alternatively you can use [LTHPasscodeViewController](https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHPasscodeViewController)